# IIS rewrite: Outbound rewrite rules cannot be applied when the content of the http response is encoded ("identity")

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, reverse-proxy

I've set up an IIS reverse proxy to serve some content from within WSL with the following web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule1" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost:6006/{R:1}" />
                    <serverVariables>
                        <set name="HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_ACCEPT_ENCODING" value="{HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING}" />
                        <set name="HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING" value="" />
                    </serverVariables>
                </rule>
            </rules>
            <outboundRules>
                <rule name="ReverseProxyOutboundRule1" preCondition="ResponseIsHtml1">
                    <match filterByTags="A, Form, Img" pattern="^http(s)?://localhost:6006/(.*)" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" value="http{R:1}://iansdesktop/{R:2}" />
                </rule>
                <preConditions>
                    <preCondition name="ResponseIsHtml1">
                        <add input="{RESPONSE_CONTENT_TYPE}" pattern="^text/html" />
                    </preCondition>
                </preConditions>
            </outboundRules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

However, this results in a 500.52 error complaining that the response is encoded (it isn't encoded, I've verified with telnet) and the encoding reported is "[identity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9378950/httpwebresponse-content-encoding-identity)" which apparently means no encoding at all.

How can I change my rules to fix this?

Comment: I tested the rewrite rules you provided, and the error was: Outbound rewrite rules cannot be applied when the content of the HTTP response is encoded ("gzip"). Then I added two variables named HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING and HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_ACCEPT_ENCODING, and the corresponding server variables are also set in the rules, just solved this error. Of course, I did not set the identity in the code.  I don't see your code on how to set identity  and error page, I'm not sure when the response was encoded. What value should the header have and what effect do you want to get?

Comment: @JennyDai The identity header value is coming from a third party package called tensorboard: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard As I understand it the "identity" value should be ignored by the rewrite module as it means "no encoding".

Comment: You can try to modify the outbound rules, when you receive the responses from the backend server, you need to forward them back to the browser. To be able to correctly do this, you will need to restore the value of the HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING variable to what it was before you changed it to empty. Refer the following link：https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/iis-support-blog/iis-acting-as-reverse-proxy-where-the-problems-start/ba-p/846259#M344

Comment: @JennyDai Hi, the response is not being encoded by the backend server. I have verified this by connecting to the server with telnet. I have temporarily solved this issue by commenting out the header in the source of the third party web site: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard/blob/master/tensorboard/plugins/core/core_plugin.py#L171